# Processing.js and ColdFusion Server with IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, coldfusion-8, processing.js

I am trying to use [Processing.js](http://processingjs.org/) on our ColdFusion server and having no luck.  If I take a regular html program, that runs fine locally, and save it to our server, the canvas will not show in IE 11. However, it displays fine with Chrome.

Unfortunately, the app I am trying to fold this into was not written to be cross browser and needs IE.  Has anyone gotten processing to work on a ColdFusion server using IE as the browser?

Comment: Not sure why this is tagged under CF. If it is an html page, then it has nothing to do with CF. I am not familiar with Processing.js, but you need to post more information (like a *small* [repro case](http://www.sscce.org/) ), for anyone to assist

Comment: the reason it is under CF is that this is where I tried it, first as a cfm, and then when that didn't work, since it had on cf tags, I tried it as straight HTML.    The same code works find if I run it locally on my machine with any browser I tried, and works on CF server with using Chrome, but not IE.    IE works fine locally.  I don't know what repo case is (even after clicking), but if you are talking about a code sample, I will send that next.

Comment: A "repro case" is simply an example, ie the smallest amount of code that repro[duces] the issue. However, it is hard to say if it is purely an HTML/JS issue, or somehow related to CF, without any code.

Comment: I tried to post the code but displays devoid of all white spacing and pretty much unitellagable.  I tried the single quotes as shown below, but it was still minified.  How can I show code on this site?

Comment: [Back ticks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent) (not single quotes) can used for small bits of inline code. For larger blocks of code, use the code button ie `{}` on the toolbar or [indent fours spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).